# How to remove iframe body class (JQuery / JS)

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I have this code:

```
<ul class="heroBx">
    <li>
        <iframe width="980" height="370" src="heroBanner/heroElantra/index.html" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>
    </li>
    <li>
        <iframe width="980" height="370" src="heroBanner/heroH1/index.html" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>
    </li>
    <li>
        <iframe width="980" height="370" src="heroBanner/heroStarex/index.html" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>
    </li>
    <li>
        <iframe width="980" height="370" src="heroBanner/heroTucson/index.html" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>
    </li>
    <li>
        <iframe width="980" height="370" src="heroBanner/heroVeloster/index.html" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Can I remove iframe body class?
Thank you.

Comment: your iframes don't have a class! you mean the ul class?

Comment: @AminJafari i want remove body class of iframe sorry my English is not very well.

Comment: @user3755490 – Did either of the answers below help solve your issue? thx~

Answer (score 0):

`document.querySelectorAll('.my #awesome selector');`

and

`el.classList.remove(className);`

http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/

So if you want to remove the `heroBx` class from all `ul` elements in the DOM via JavaScript:

```
var uls = document.querySelectorAll('ul');
for(var i = 0; i < uls.length; i++) {
  uls[i].classList.remove('heroBx');
}
```

If there's only one `ul` to target, you could instead simply:

```
var ul = document.querySelector('ul');
ul.classList.remove('heroBx');
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
$('#iframe').contents().find('body').attr('class','');
```

Comment: Try this & explain if any problem